# ActiveControl is hidden

Tags: vb.net, winforms

To boil the situation down, I have a panel with 3 textboxes on it. When I hide the panel, the first textbox in the tab order for the panel gets assigned to Me.ActiveControl (The form), regardless of which one was focused when the panel was hidden.

I thought a hidden control could never have focus. I have other controls on my form where the issue was originally found, so I thought it would have to choose a non hidden control to focus on. Is this a bug, or designed this way?

I use a timer on my simple form that fires every 5 seconds, recording the active control name in a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to recreate your scenario and it revealed an interesting possibility (more on this later).

WinForms has the concept of the *Selected* (or activated) control. The [Control.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) is related to the [Control.Focus Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focus?view=netframework-4.7.2).  The [Focus Method-Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focus?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) documentation is relevant.

> A control can be selected and receive input focus if all the following
>   are true: the Selectable value of ControlStyles is set to true, it is
>   contained in another control, and all its parent controls are both
>   visible and enabled.

...

> Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control
>   authors. Instead, application programmers should use the Select method
>   or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or the Activate
>   method for forms.

The [ContainerControl.ActiveControl Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2) points to the last *selected* control.

The reason that the first control by tab order in the `Panel` is selected is due to the code that executes when the `Panel.Visible` property is set to false.  The [Visible Property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,34eb26e129516529) setter calls [SetVisibleCore](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs.html#25c694f788775284) that in turn calls [SelectNextIfFocused](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,e92b8ded2ad80712) that calls [SelectNextControlInternal](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,b09a17179548f912,references) that finally calls [Control.SelectNextControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2) that selects the your `TextBox1`.

This is where it gets interesting.  At this point the `Panel` and `TextBox` are both visible.  Therefore, the `TextBox` receives focus and retains it when the `Panel` is hidden.  This condition allows for a hidden `TextBox` to have keyboard input and no rules about a hidden control not being able to receive focus are violated.

Comment: First off thanks for your detailed response. I really appreciate it. That's interesting behavior. I can definitely work around it, I just thought it was some kind of bug.

I can't vote you up yet...